# ¿Como cambiar un evento en jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Tengo una modal la cual tiene dos funciones, plasmar los datos recibidos por `ajax`en etiquetas `<span class="nombre"></span>`
y la otra alternativa es poder darle la opción al usuario que cuando oprima un botón esos datos se conviertan en un formulario...

la funcion es la siguiente:

 para mostrar los datos sin editar uso `$('.nombre').html(data[0].nombre);`

pero quiero que cuando se oprima el boton `"editar"` cambie ese `$('.nombre').html(data[0].nombre);` por el `$('.nombre').val(data[0].nombre);`, ¿con que fin? con el fin de que no tenga que volver hacer un llamado ajax para volver a plasmar los datos en los `inputs` del formulario a editar.

ya que que si uso `$('.nombre').html(data[0].nombre);` no se me va a mostrar ese dato en el `input` del formulario.

Espero haberme hecho entender y agradeceria el interes

Comment: Puedes colocar el código de lo que recibes y como lo estas intentando plasmar?

Comment: No está muy claro lo que preguntas. Por favor edita la pregunta para añadir detalles y un [mcve] si es posible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, lo más simple en vez de cambiar el evento de acuerdo a la situación, puede ser enviar los valores al elemento correspondiente de la manera correspondiente.

Por ejemplo:

en el caso de tener estos dos elementos:

`<input class="nombre" /> <span class="nombre"></span>`

podes especificar mediante el selector a cuáles quieres pasarle el valor de la forma adecuada.

```
$('input.nombre').val('nombre');
$('span.nombre').html('nombre');
```

Esto te va a permitir ejecutar el mismo código sin importar si los elementos son visibles o no.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('input.nombre').val('nombre');
  $('span.nombre').html('nombre');
}, 1500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="nombre" /> <span class="nombre"></span>
```